# Return type is union instead of being narrowed

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[Link to a replication of the problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngVQA4AmckyA3gFDLIQbYCSBAXMgM5hSgDmA3JdbVgAqWPBGYAiAGJ0ASgGVBAfVQA5QXUEBNRVoAKqccgA%20ycXNQBhAPIqAIsrUbteg8l4BfcuVCRYiFJLAUGzoYJhYZHzATKzsXB7e4NDwSMiBwWCh4fhEJBAAHpAgBCxoAjnEKBRUNGHYzOkhArw1AsKiEtLySqrqWjqa%20uIJib4pKHIQCAD2xVnYkVTRzGwcIDzknj7J-siTM3PlhJXUhTQlZXW4xyTV-FfM%207ME81gt9%20HtYqbm1nYOfWcgwMI2woku2RuEBwIGAs2QAF40kEmlcKiQTE9DmiobxyAc2BDsF9EYs0rIFACnAN9J0KT1HP0XIY4KUCWAADR8X42ey9akuCQ8-78pnAlls2ZsLnuXhglCvElI17o6Gw2YAbXEtU%20Igg4gAunj5UTrrkIF9JNMoAAeQSKvWnIoXB2iAB8pNQhSgiDANr4KqhMLhIC5VBkU2tBBt2raevEHOQ9rj7vIbrljtdECttuTVxJBWdpSzHoRAaO5st1rtJa1Ouwhrx2z8qQjeGmLEw1qwoSgWBrKZQhfOxcHHru9awDBWcXW7wANqywKrmIHK3qcwP83r05svCbXnIwNaIFvdeDh8VR9v3aSIzMoNG%20KsuGHkG2O12%2073%203nzxA3TTY1HQ-Ttjz7Uk7g1P9iUdUBTS%20A1VwEI8TzPWD3Q8PF2XfCB22YUCvwiJEoKzAA6LpKVFIF9CQsh3DfDVyOFPlGRo1A6NIBjNjxcgYAAVxABAwnhTgIDAABBed5zXSoWAAISEPV0KUi8zivBCdwACj4ScvmYGDVIgcgAEoySgcT%20KgEBkCsAAjAArKYwDIgA3OB534iAWC0j8NT0vUDRMsiAFs4DwLStIgMyEQ9CAyMXNhVRMkYBKEkSbLEyTpPmYBvMUr4VILdSXTHHTWhvb5DK%20UzzMs6zbMc5y3I8ryfL8gLRCC0Lwsi6LETihKl1VMjJxSvd8SlMBkBgFFMgrOTSSyqSZIWyAFKMrTyMohlARpVBxpw2aMly7ylvElbTo2r4tsHCj6SpMV9BSoA)

```
const firstEntityUpdates // inferred type FirstEntityUpdate[]
const firstEntities  // inferred type (FirstEntity|SecondEntity)[]
```

On line 69 the discriminated union is correctly inferred for the firstEntityUpdates assignment.

On 70, why does the firstEntities assignment return a union and not narrow to FirstEntity which is what I expect/desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

I see that you already have a generic type, so you could just add this to the return statement to have typescript infer the response type

```js
return Object.values(Repo[entityType]).map((e) => e.lastUpdate.entity) as EntityTypeFor<TEntityType>[]
```

---

I was playing around with it, and I am by no means an expert, but if you make a generic response type

```js
type GenericResponseType<T extends string> = T extends "FIRST_ENTITY_TYPE" ? FirstEntity[] : SecondEntity[];
```

and then declare your response for `getAllEntitiesByType` like

```js
function getAllEntitiesByType<TEntityType extends EntityType>(
  entityType: TEntityType
): GenericResponseType<TEntityType> {
  return Object.values(Repo[entityType]).map((e) => e.lastUpdate.entity);
}
```

The type gets correctly inferred

Heres the docs on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: Thanks Markos.  That certainly works but I suppose it's being explicit about the return type and expressing that in terms of the type parameter using the generic.  Ideally I am looking to understand why the type wasn't narrowing as I expect 
Thanks for the response!